# DRF 1.7.1 'str' object has no attribute 'resolve' AttributeError

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm trying to make my first DRF api working but when I try to make a GET request using curl or a web browser i.e. I'm getting the 'str' object has no attribute 'resolve' AttributeError.
The adress I use for my test is: http://0.0.0.0:8000/polls/expediteur/

I leave some code snippets below.

**urls.py**

```py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from polls import views
# from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    "polls.view",
    url(r'^Expediteur/$', views.ExpeViewSet.as_view(), name="expediteur"),
)
```

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Expediteur(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    prenom = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tel = models.IntegerField()
```

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from polls.serializers import ExpediteurSerializer, DestinataireSerializer, LettrePrioSerializer, TypeLettreRecoSerializer, LettreRecoSerializer, TimbrePrioSerializer, TimbreRecoSerializer
from polls.models import Expediteur, Destinataire, LettrePrio, TypeLettreReco, LettreReco, TimbrePrio, TimbreReco
from rest_framework import status, HTTP_HEADER_ENCODING
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

import json
import datetime

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse, Http404
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.timezone import get_current_timezone

# Create your views here.

class ExpeViewSet(APIView):
    serializer_class = ExpediteurSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = Expediteur.objects.all()
        serializer = ExpediteurSerializer(queryset)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.DATA)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from polls.models import Expediteur, Destinataire, LettrePrio, TypeLettreReco, LettreReco, TimbrePrio, TimbreReco


class ExpediteurSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    nom = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, max_length=50)
    prenom = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, max_length=100)
    adresse = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, max_length=200)
    tel = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Expediteur.objects.create(**validated_data)
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.nom = validated_data.get('nom', instance.nom)
        instance.prenom = validated_data.get('prenom', instance.prenom)
        instance.adresse = validated_data.get('adresse', insatnce.adresse)
        instance.tel = validated_data.get('tel', instance.tel)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

There's already two ExpediteurObject and my goal is to be able to interact with it in a mobile app. I already check on ['str' object has no attribute 'resolve' when access admin site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020523/str-object-has-no-attribute-resolve-when-access-admin-site) and http://redsymbol.net/articles/django-attributeerror-str-object-no-attribute-resolve/

to see if I could solve the problem but I didn't found the answer to my problem.

I also leave the traceback below

**Traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://0.0.0.0:8000/polls/expediteur/

Django Version: 1.7.1
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'polls')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  98.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  345.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /polls/expediteur/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'resolve'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `"polls.view",` string from the `patterns()`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^Expediteur/$', views.ExpeViewSet.as_view(), name="expediteur"),
)
```

To access the view at the `/polls/expediteur/` address change the url to:

```
url(r'^polls/expediteur/$', views.ExpeViewSet.as_view(), name="expediteur"),
```

Or, if this `urls.py` is from the `polls` app:

```
url(r'^expediteur/$', views.ExpeViewSet.as_view(), name="expediteur"),
```

Comment: Just tryed it, it solve indeed my AttributeError but I get instead an error 404 <br/> 
Page not found (404)
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://0.0.0.0:8000/polls/expediteur/

Using the URLconf defined in CUP.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^Expediteur/$ [name='expediteur']

The current URL, polls/expediteur/, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: Change the regex to `r'^polls/expediteur/$'` as I showed in the updated answer.

Comment: Just tried again I get a strange AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `nom` on serializer `ExpediteurSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `type` instance.
Original exception text was: type object 'QuerySet' has no attribute 'nom'.

Comment: I never used DRF so can't help here.

Comment: I' ll make another post.