# Recording classes in Django Admin with @admin.register decorator

Tags: python-3.x, django-admin, decorator, django-1.8

I am testing the new `@admin.register` decorator that is a new feature from Django 1.7.
I am currently using Django 1.8.2 and Python 3 and happened me the following situation in relation to `@admin.register` decorator:

In my `admin.py` file I have:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Track

# Register your models here.
@admin.register(Track)
class TrackAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title','artist')
```

And when I try `http://localhost:8000/admin/` I get the following output in my browser:

[image: AttributeError]

Now, When I use the `admin.site.register(Track,TrackAdmin)`that is the traditional way of register models and classes in the django admin, happened me the same

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Track


# Register your models here.

class TrackAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title','artist')

admin.site.register(Track,TrackAdmin)
```

How to can I use the @admin.register decorator for record together classes? `(Track and TrackAdmin)`

Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Please see following reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/

Place your decorator @admin.register(Track) before your class as a wrapper for it.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Track

# Register your models here

@admin.register(Track)
class TrackAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title','artist')
```

---

Comment: I've updated above my question. It's true, the admin.register decorator is before to the class. Now my error is related to 'str' object has no attribute 'regex'  but I've solved the problem according to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020523/str-object-has-no-attribute-resolve-when-access-admin-site My problem was that I have commented out some url()s using triple-quotes. All my admin and models in it are good and working. :)

Comment: Accept this as the answer, @bgarcial?

Answer (score 0):

Enter you decorator in admin.py file and not in models.py:

```
from .models import *

@admin.register(Track)
```